# Configure OCW to run every x blocks or on demand

Tags: offchain-worker, offchain-storage

I understand that off-chain workers are spawned during [block import](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/transaction-lifecycle/#block-authoring-and-block-imports), [quote](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/offchain-operations/#off-chain-workers):

> Offchain workers are spawned during each block import. However, they aren't executed during initial blockchain synchronization.

I was wondering if there is any way to configure OCWs to be spawned either:

- in specific intervals, e.g. every 10 blocks, or
- on demand (e.g. during block import on a specific height)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the block number inside the offchain worker so you can also encapsulate the whole logic inside the if clause.

Example:

```rust
fn offchain_worker() {
    let current_block_num = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
    
    if current_block_number % 10 == 0 {
        logic_to_run_every_10_block();
    } else if currenct_block_number == x {
        logic_to_run_on_block_x();
    }

}
```